# How to render none sharpy element when saved as png?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

So basically I have an artwork which render like this :

[image]

But when I try to integrate it in a website it get itself all pixelised (probably due to the fact that I'm saving it as png).

[image]

So is there a trick for outpassing this kind of behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try saving the graphic as PNG-24. PNG-24 is 24 bits per pixel which can handle a lot more colors and transparencies.

> In addition to supporting background transparency and background
>   matting, the PNG‑24 format supports multilevel transparency. You can
>   have up to 256 degrees of transparency from opaque to completely
>   transparent, so you can blend the edges of an image smoothly with any
>   background color. However, not all browsers support multilevel
>   transparency.

[Photoshop Elements Help / Optimizing images for the PNG-24 format](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/optimizing-images-png-24-format.html)